# How to get the Device ID of PCI devices?

Tags: c#, wmi, device, pci

I am trying to get the system device IDs from the device manager, in C#. I found some code to find the USB device ID, but I don't know how to change the code from USB device to PCI device.

This is the code that I found:

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDevices WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");    
 foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())     
 {
      ManagementObject query = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + mo["DeviceID"] + "'");      
      Console.WriteLine(query["SerialNumber"]);    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to MSDN, **Win32_PhysicalMedia** represents any type of documentation or storage medium.
If you want to get DeviceID from PCI device (like as in Device Manager at Control Panel) - you need **Win32_PnPEntity** class, which represents the properties of a Plug and Play device. So, try to use this code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
     Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}", queryObj["DeviceID"]);
     Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
}
```

Running this code provides me lots of info about my PCI devices